# Add Remove element with Jquery using a refrence to html element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add an element to a dropDown and after selection remove it, by naively trying to have htmlElement refrence defines as such : (Of course this doeasnt work)

```
var selectAnOption = "<option value='' selected='selected'>Select One</option>";
```

So later

```
 var addSelectAnOption = function () { ('#ddb1').prepend(selectAnOption ); };

var removeSelectAnOption = function () { selectAnOption.remove(); };
```

I have also tried the following variation:

```
var selectAnOption;

 var addSelectAnOption = function () { selectAnOption = $('#ddb1').prepend("<option value='' selected='selected'>Select One</option>"); };

var removeSelectAnOption = function () { selectAnOption.remove(); };
```

But this also didn't work, as selectAnOption was set to the dropDownBox itself

Of course I could add the option with an id and then later use that to find it to remove it, but that seemed not too pretty.

Comment: Assuming only one `option` is ever selected at one time, you could use `$('option[selected="selected"]').remove();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrap it in `$()`:

```
var selectAnOption = $("<option value='' selected='selected'>Select One</option>");
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/6fxb66x1/)